# Deploying express server code as firebase cloud function for react app

Tags: javascript, firebase, rest, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have the following express server code which I would like to run as a firebase cloud function. However I have this error (page not found) `POST https://vid-chat-app.web.app/video/token 404`. What am I doing wrong here?

```
const config = require('./config');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const pino = require('express-pino-logger')();
const { videoToken } = require('./tokens');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(pino);

const sendTokenResponse = (token, res) => {
  res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send(
    JSON.stringify({
      token: token.toJwt()
    })
  );
};

app.post('/video/token', (req, res) => {
  const identity = req.body.identity;
  const room = req.body.room;
  const token = videoToken(identity, room, config);
  sendTokenResponse(token, res);
});
```

This is my attempt to do convert the code to a cloud function

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const config = require('./config');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const pino = require('express-pino-logger')();
const { videoToken } = require('./tokens');

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(pino);

const sendTokenResponse = (token, res) => {
  res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send(
    JSON.stringify({
      token: token.toJwt()
    })
  );
};

app.post('/video/token', (req, res) => {
  const identity = req.body.identity;
  const room = req.body.room;
  const token = videoToken(identity, room, config);
  sendTokenResponse(token, res);
});

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

Here is the firebase.json file

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/video/token",
        "destination": "app"
      },
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  }
}
```

And here is the api request in the react app

```
  const handleSubmit = useCallback(
    async event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      const data = await fetch('/video/token', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
          identity: username,
          room: roomName
        }),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      }).then(res => res.json());
      setToken(data.token);
    },
    [roomName, username]
  );
```

**UPDATE**

I have edited part of the firebase.json file to

{
"source": "/video/token",
"function": "app"
},

That seems to work. I have created a test GET request and tested the address https://vid-chat-app.web.app/video/token on Postman. It works! However, I now have the following 500 error

```
Error: accountSid is required
    at new AccessToken (/srv/node_modules/twilio/lib/jwt/AccessToken.js:213:28)
    at generateToken (/srv/tokens.js:6:10)
    at videoToken (/srv/tokens.js:20:17)
    at app.get (/srv/index.js:32:17)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/srv/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
```

Comment: As per the [twilio code](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/blob/main/lib/jwt/AccessToken.js#L213) if you don't provide one parameter an error is thrown. In the other side [Express code](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/router/index.js#L335) just call the callback function so as far as I understand the issue could be in "tokens.js". Can you please provide the **tokens.js** sanitized code?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
app.post('/app', (req, res) => { ... })
```

since that's what the Cloud Functions URI would be if Hosting hadn't forwarded the request.

You could also try:

```
app.post('/app/video/token', (req, res) => { ... })
```

Comment: Hi @Doug I think I should be using "function": "app" in firebase.json? Doing that, I now get a 500 server error. The error on firebase states an accountSid is required. Is there a process for using the .env file (it is outside the functions folder) within cloud functions?

Comment: It sounds like you have a completely new problem that's unrelated to the first.  I suggest posting a new question in that case.

Comment: "`since that's what the Cloud Functions URI would be if Hosting hadn't forwarded the request`" - but don't the cloud functions take care of the server, so that `app` isn't even defined?